# Could not find :UnityAds:. Required by: project :app > project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am trying to import and embed a unity project into an existing android project. I have read and followed tutorials but I keep getting an error **Could not find :UnityAds:.
Required by:
    project :app > project :tester
Search in build.gradle files**

I want to open a unity scene in my android app.

Answer (score 1):

First off - Is there a good reason for embedding a Unity app in your Android application?

Unity Ads is a built in Unity Service (see image).
I would suggest getting the project to work in Unity - with Unity Ads, before going through the process of embedding it in your android app.

[image: Unity Ads Service]